# New to JS and having trouble!

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I am new to JavaScript and I have been working on this assignment all day and I am extremly frustrated. I cannot figure out what I have done wrong or what code I may have missed. Any help is greatly appreciated it!! Below is the the assignment and the code I have done already. Thank you!!

Assignment:
Many companies normally charge a shipping and handling charge for purchases. Create a
Web page that allows a user to enter a purchase price into a text box and includes a
JavaScript function that calculates shipping and handling. Add functionality to the script
that adds a minimum shipping and handling charge of $1.50 for any purchase that is less
than or equal to $25.00. For any orders over $25.00, add 10% to the total purchase price
for shipping and handling, but do not include the $1.50 minimum shipping and handling
charge. The formula for calculating a percentage is price * percent / 100. For example, the
formula for calculating 10% of a $50.00 purchase price is 50 * 10 / 100, which results in a
shipping and handling charge of $5.00. After you determine the total cost of the order
(purchase plus shipping and handling), display it in an alert dialog box. Save the document
as CalcShipping.html.

Code written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js_styles.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Calculating Shipping & Handling</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* ![CDATA[ */

getShipping();
{
    if (price <= 25.00)
    shipping = 1.50
    else (price > 25.00)
    shipping = (price * (10/100));
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* ![CDATA[ */ 
document.write("<h1>Purchase Price with Shipping</h1>");
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var price=prompt("What is your purchase price?");

getShipping();
document.write ("<p>The purchase price entered is $" + (price) + "</p>");
document.write ("<p>Shipping is $" + (shipping) + "</p>");

var total = price + shipping; 
document.write("Your total price with shipping is $ " + (total) + "");

/* ]]> */
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You wrote this:

```
getShipping();
{
    if (price <= 25.00)
    shipping = 1.50
    else (price > 25.00)
    shipping = (price * (10/100));
}
```

That's calling a currently undefined function and then enters a block. To define a function, you have to use the `function` keyword:

```
function getShipping()
{
    if (price <= 25.00)
    shipping = 1.50
    else (price > 25.00)
    shipping = (price * (10/100));
}
```

You also wrote `else (price > 25.00)`. You either need to add an `if` after the `else` (making it `else if (price > 25.00)`) or drop the `(price > 25.00)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in this code:

```
else (price > 25)
```

You are missing an if after the else:

```
else if (price > 25)
```

However, as the second condition is the exact inverse of the first, you don't need it. You can just use:

```
else
```